# Reading Redis Info

Tags: redis

My laptop has only 8GB RAM, I tried to stress test my app, which uses Redis heavily. When I looked at INFO output I couldn't figure out how used memory can be 31.83GB. Rdb dump is only 300 mb.

```
# Memory
used_memory:34177666096
used_memory_human:31.83G
used_memory_rss:412901376
used_memory_peak:34175483600
used_memory_peak_human:31.83G
used_memory_lua:31744
mem_fragmentation_ratio:0.01
mem_allocator:libc
```

Questions:

Why Rdb dump is so small and used_memory_human is so big? How to identify actual memory usage (INFO shows something different)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis does not use the same representation of data in memory and on disk. Each one is optimized. The in memory representation is optimized for access speed, while the on-disk representation reduces disk space usage. So you can't compare the size of the file with the RAM used.

used_memory / used_memory_human is the memory that was allocated to Redis by libc. As it is much greater than used_memory_rss, which is the size as seen by the OS, it means your system is swapping, so you should expect some performance issues.